# Fail2ban mail customisation

Tags: debian, security, fail2ban

I didn't find where to customise the fail2ban mail messages, i want to change the subject.

i know i need to see the action hook like this :

```
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s]
               %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s]
```

but nothing on the subject.

Comment: Look at the actual ban actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the fail2ban installation.  On Debian-based Linux installations, most of the email actions are located in the `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/` folder in files that start with mail and sendmail.  Specifically, the "action_mwl" action you are referencing calls `mail-whois-lines` or `sendmail-whois-lines` depending on which MTA you selected.  Those two actions are located in  `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/mail-whois-lines.conf` and `sendmail-whois-lines.conf`.

If you want to remove the subject line, remove the -s and the actual quoted subject from the mail command in `mail-whois-lines.conf`, or the subject line from the headers in `sendmail-whois-lines.conf` in the banaction action in those files.  Of course, do it in the one that corresponds to the mail transport agent you are using.